# Send String over netcat connection

Tags: python, netcat

I have two virtual machines open, one is listening on the connection, the other connects with `nc <ip> <port>` from a python subprocess call. I want to send just 1 line of text over the connection then close it. I know how to send a file cat `cat <file> | nc <ip> <port>` but how can I just send a line of text in the nc command (without using files)?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I don't want to use files at all in any way, just strings

Comment: Is there any way to capture this data (text) reached to another VM which is listening on the connection.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo -n 'Line of text' | nc <ip> <port>
```

You can also use temp file syntax:

```
cat <(echo "Line of test") | nc <ip> <port>
```

Comment: With `cat | nc -vl localhost` you can make netcat send data to the client from standard in, your keyboard for example. This works after the connection was established with the client.

Answer (score 3):

The temp file syntax shown by @cb0 could also be used as:

```
nc <ip> <port> <( echo "Line of text" )
```

without having to use `cat` command. This would create a temporary file with the content "Line of text" and then redirect it to the netcat command.

Answer (score 1):

Create file `test.txt`, content of file is 1

```
netcat [ip-address] [port] <test.txt
```

At destination you must have something to listen to this.

Answer (score 1):

`-N` flag is required to exit `nc` after a message is sent for some servers:

```bash
echo "text" | nc -N <ip> <port>
```

> -N shutdown(2) the network socket after EOF on the input.
> Some servers require this to finish their work.
>
> -- `man nc`